# Can't install git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

Trying to install git flow

Run:

```
brew install git-flow
```

Got:

```
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-flow--git
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing: git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git
```

Also run:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo sh
```

Got:

```
Submodule path 'shFlags': checked out '2fb06af13de884e9680f14a00c82e52a67c867f1'
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow-init: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow-feature: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow-hotfix: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow-release: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow-support: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/git-flow-version: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/gitflow-common: No such file or directory
install: /usr/local/bin/gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you still have the issue? (there was a DDOS on GitHub earlier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that you have some problems with your SSH keys.
I think it safe to assume that you use a Macintosh  because the `brew` command.

So here's how i would fix that.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
```

Leave the following empty for if you want it to be default.
And leave the passphrase also empty if you don't want a password

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa): [id_dsa or empty] 
Enter passphrase (empty for no password):

Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in id_dsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
16:8e:e8:f2:1d:c9:b9:cf:43:9a:b3:3c:c1:1f:95:93 user@localhost
```

Here's also a [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-mac) to GitHub about adding your ssh key to github.